# Trouble with passing array to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am supposed to use a string array to output the line "Enter rainfall for x", x being the name of a month, and having the input be sent to a separate array for calculations. Currently, when I run my code I am seeing "Enter rainfall for 1", "Enter rainfall for 2", etc. instead of "Enter rainfall for January", "Enter rainfall for February". Aside from this, the code also needs to show the total, average, and lowest and highest months of rainfall. I am able to have the program output the correct total and average however, the highest and lowest month just outputs a random number instead of a month name.

I have attempted to create prototypes and call an array to a function but I think the issue might be contributed to the fact that I am having issues with my string array. I have tried using a for loop, I've tried changing my syntax to no avail. I don't currently get any errors in the debugging process only see incorrect output instead of a string output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
void getMonthlyRainfall(double[], int);
double getTotal(const double[], int);
double getHighestAmount(const double[], int);
double getLowestAmount(const double[], int);

int main()
{
    const int MONTHS = 12;
    string monthNames[MONTHS] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", 
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", 
    "December" };
     double rainfall[MONTHS], // Array
        total,
        average,
        lowestAmount,
        highestAmount;

    //Get rainfall input from user
    getMonthlyRainfall(rainfall, MONTHS);

    // Get the total amount of rain for the year
    total = getTotal(rainfall, MONTHS);

    // Get the average rainfall
    average = total / MONTHS;

    // Get the month with the lowest rainfall
    lowestAmount = getLowestAmount(rainfall, MONTHS);

    // Get the month with the highest rainfall
    highestAmount = getHighestAmount(rainfall, MONTHS);

    cout << "Total rainfall: " << total << endl;
    cout << "Average rainfall: " << average << endl;
    cout << "Least rainfall in: " << getLowestAmount << endl;
    cout << "Most rainfall in: " << getHighestAmount << endl;
    return 0;
}

void getMonthlyRainfall(double rain[], int size) 
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 12; index++)
    {
        cout << "Enter rainfall for " << (index + 1) << ": ";
        cin >> rain[index];
    }
}

double getTotal(const double numbers[], int size) 
{
    double total = 0; // Accumulator
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
        total += numbers[count];
    return total;
}

double getHighestAmount(const double numbers[], int size) 
{
    double highest; // Holds highest value
    // Get array's first element
    highest = numbers[0];
    // Step through array
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) 
    {
        if (numbers[count] > highest)
            highest = numbers[count];
    }
    return highest;
}

double getLowestAmount(const double numbers[], int size) 
{
    double lowest; // Holds lowest value
    // Get array's first element
    lowest = numbers[0];
    // Step through array
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (numbers[count] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[count];
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

As I stated the first output should say the actual name of a month and it should be in order. For instance, the prompt should first ask the user to input total rainfall for the month of January, the user inputs a number. The prompt then goes on to ask the user input a number for February, so on and so forth until December. I am instead seeing the prompt ask the user to input total rainfall for "1", user inputs a number, the prompt then asks user to input rainfall for "2" until it gets to 12. The program does the calculations and outputs correct total and average but when it is supposed to output "Month with highest (or lowest) rainfall: (Month name)" it instead gives me a random number such as 01201686.

So to sum up, the string array outputs month name and the user input is stored in a separate array for calculations. Those calculations are outputted for total and average but the rainfall totals need to be compared to the month with the corresponding entity and the output for highest and lowest then needs to be a string not a number.

Comment: While compiling do NOT ignore the compiler warnings. Compiler warnings are the compiler telling you that while the code is syntactically correct, it compiles, it is probably logically incorrect and will crash, misbehave or even look like it's behaving right up until suddenly it doesn't.

Comment: I would like to recommend: Please do not use plain C-Style arrays. Please try to use STL containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple confusion over names. You have the name of the function (which will print as a 'random' number) instead of the name of the variable you are using.

```
cout << "Least rainfall in: " << getLowestAmount << endl;
```

should be

```
cout << "Least rainfall in: " << lowestAmount << endl;
```

As for your first quesiton, change

```
cout << "Enter rainfall for " << (index + 1) << ": ";
```

to

```
cout << "Enter rainfall for " << monthNames[index] << ": ";
```

Obviously the first version prints a number (`index + 1` is a number). To get the month name you have to use the number as an index to your array of month names.

To make this work you also will need to make `monthNames` available in the `getMonthlyRainfall` function (at the moment it's only visible in `main`). You should pass `monthNames` to the `getMonthlyRainfall` function like this

```
void getMonthlyRainfall(double[], string[], int);
```

and

```
//Get rainfall input from user
getMonthlyRainfall(rainfall, monthNames, MONTHS);
```

and

```
void getMonthlyRainfall(double rain[], string monthNames[], int size) 
{
    ...
```

EDIT

So to output both lowest monthly rainfall and the name of the month with the lowest rainfall you should change your `getLowestAmount` function to return the **index** of the month with the lowest rainfall. You should also change the name of this function because it's now doing something different from the original function and the old name does not accurately describe the new function, but for clarity I'll leave it the same. You can decide on a new name later.

```
// this function returns a month index, not a rainfall amount,
// so it's return type is int not double
int getLowestAmount(const double[], int);
```

Here's the updated function

```
int getLowestAmount(const double numbers[], int size) 
{
    double lowest; // Holds lowest value
    int lowestIndex; // Holds the index of the lowest value
    // Get array's first element
    lowest = numbers[0];
    lowestIndex = 0;
    // Step through array
    for (int count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (numbers[count] < lowest)
        {
            lowest = numbers[count];
            lowestIndex = count;
        }
    }
    return lowestIndex;
}
```

See the function is the same except I've added `lowestIndex` and that's the value I return.

Now in `main` you can use the lowest index to print both values that you want to see

```
// Get the month with the lowest rainfall
lowestIndex = getLowestAmount(rainfall, MONTHS);

...

cout << "Least rainfall in: " << monthNames[lowestIndex] << 
    " is " << rainfall[lowestIndex] << endl;
```

Comment: This suggestion has helped a lot in terms of seeing what I was doing wrong in my functions and I was able to get the output of the month names correctly,I am still having an issue with the function arguments to output the month names. The suggestion about making monthNames available in my functions helped me to be able to output the number of highest rainfall but I am supposed to output the month with the highest and lowest rainfall as opposed to the actual number. For instance, if September had 1 inch of rain and was the lowest month, the output would say "Least rainfall in September."

Comment: I believe I'm supposed to take whatever the element is for amount of rainfall and compare it to the element in a parallel array for the corresponding month but I am unable to figure out how to word the parallel array since one array is a string and the other is a double.

Comment: @Sydniewyatt OK then you should change your `getLowestAmount` function so that instead of returning the *lowest amount* it returns the *index of month in which the lowest rainfall occurs*. Then once you know the lowest month index, you can use that to print both the month name and the amount of rainfall. Is that clear? I'll update my answer if not.

Comment: I understand that I need the index of the month with lowest rainfall but I have been trying to use a parallel array to compare the monthNames [count] and numbers [count] to output monthNames[count]. This is what I have been putting in my function/loop to try to get an output:                                               
 if (rainfall[count] < lowest)
    lowest = rainfall[count];
    monthNames[count] = lowest;                                   After this I assume the index will be outputted when I call it in the main function but it is still showing a number output

Comment: @Sydniewyatt No that's not right, I'll update my answer.

Comment: This makes more sense to me now that I'm looking at it, in terms of returning lowest(a number) instead of lowestIndex(the index of the number). I was able to adjust those things but I actually don't need to output the amount of rainfall, just the month name corresponding to the lowest amount. I left out the rainfall[index] portion for cout however now I am getting a "subscript is not of integral type" compiler error for that line. I see that this error means the subscript is not an integer expression but shouldn't I be able to output strings from arrays?

Comment: @Sydniewyatt I'm guessing that you done this `cout << monthNames[lowestAmount]` but you still have `double lowestAmount;` If lowestAmount is really an index then it should be `int lowestAmount;` not double. That's what the error message is saying, what's inside the `[]` is not an integer.

Comment: @Sydniewyatt To avoid confusion between slightly different things, it's **really** important to name your variables and functions correctly.

Comment: You were absolutely right about that. Once I changed the variable to be an integer the month name popped up. Thank you so much!